# Definition of legal thread action

Tags: java, multithreading, language-lawyer

I've been trying to understand the Java Memory Model and one's multithreading sematic. Corresponding [***JLS 17.4***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of JLS 8 section says:

> To determine if the ***actions of thread t in an execution are legal***, we
>   simply evaluate the implementation of thread t as it would be
>   performed in a single-threaded context, as defined in the rest of this
>   specification.

What does the phrase I emphasized mean in that context? I mean I can't imagine **legal** and **illegal** actions of thread in an execution. Could you give an example, if any, of ones?

Comment: Please linkify citations like that when you post. I have my suspicions about the correct answer but am on my phone, and I'm not even sure which JLS version you mean.

Comment: @chrylis I'm sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the language specification; one thing it is used for is to instruct JVM writers in how their programs must behave.  Someone writing a JVM needs to know what the rules are for the language; the restrictions of the language are what they implement.  So they can write code that is 'illegal' in terms of the specification.

Let's say the JVM being written decides to do some optimizations -- it would make their JVM execute code faster than without the optimizations, perhaps give them an advantage over other JVMs who didn't do those optimizations.  One thing they could do is reorder operations, move them out of loops or whatever.  But in so doing, they make a mistake, and violate the rules of the specification.  That JVM code would be illegal, in the context that you reference.